# Gridview retrieving old values before updating

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, edit

I am using gridview to populate data, i retrieve the new values but i need the old values for reporting purposes, is there a way i could retrieve these old values?
I am using templatefield

```
     protected void TcGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {

        TcGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

        FillTravelers();
    }

            protected void TcGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = TcGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        //FillTravelers();
        TcGridView.EditIndex = -1;
        TextBox txtFC = row.FindControl("FCTextBox1") as TextBox;

        Label txtID = row.FindControl("IDLabel") as Label;
        Label txtDC = row.FindControl("DCLabel") as Label;
        Label txtRate = row.FindControl("RateLabel") as Label;

        String FC = txtFC.Text;
        String ID = txtID.Text;
        String DC = txtDC.Text;
        String Rate = txtRate.Text;

        double newDC = Convert.ToDouble(FC) / Convert.ToDouble(Rate);

        Transaction trs = new Transaction(Convert.ToInt32(ID), " ", " ", Convert.ToDouble(FC), Convert.ToDouble(Rate), newDC, " ", ID);
        DatabaseHandler.EditTransaction(trs);

        FillTravelers();
    }
```

Thanks
Karl